# How to use tooltip on toolstripbutton

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, tooltip

I'm trying to apply a tooltip to a toolstripbutton but it keeps giving me this error:

`Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' and 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton'`

Any clue on how to solve this?

**UPDATE:**

```
private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AssociatedControl == tBtn1)
    {
        using (Font f = new Font("Tahoma", 9))
        {
            e.ToolTipSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(
                toolTip1.GetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl), f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that's throwing the exception?

Comment: In what context are you getting this error. Post the code that is giving you the problem...

Comment: just cast the control to its type, ie toolstripbutton

Comment: Do what @nawfal suggested with `tBtn1` like `[..] ==(ToolStripButton)tBtn1` [...]

Comment: (e.AssociatedControl == (ToolStripButton)tBtn1)

I get the same error.

Comment: Perhaps it should be the opposite, as `tBtn1` is already typed as `ToolStripButton` (correct?), so if that's the case, `e.AssociatedControl` should be casted into `ToolStripButton`

Comment: What do you mean by "don't do that"?

Comment: Disregard that comment, I've removed it. Try casting `e.AssociatedControl` and let us know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:  After trying this out in a Winform project and not having success, I searched other threads on SO, this is one that may be helpful to you:

[Showing a tooltip on a non-focused ToolStripItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143058/showing-a-tooltip-on-a-non-focused-toolstripitem)

> The problem with the first is you can't set it to the button directly,
>   it doesn't inherit from Control, and the tooltip won't show up unless
>   you're over the strip but not over a button.

elsewhere

> I was trying to do the same thing and determined it was going to be
>   pretty challenging and not worth it. The reason is that internally,
>   the .NET code is specifically designed to only show the tooltip if the
>   window is active - they are checking this at a Win32 level so its
>   going to be hard to fake the code out.

The user never accepted any of the answers as true, and it does seem at a glance that this may be a lot of work for little reward.  Is this a project from scratch?  If so, maybe you can do it using WPF, which is much more flexible than winforms.

Comment: I updated the question with the code.
The error I get now is: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'

Comment: In the absence of him posting the code that is actually causing the problem, I could only speculate a probable cause.  I did ask him to update the code so I could update the answer.

Comment: @GrayFox374 so since now u understand his code, kindly update or remove the answer. I will cancel my -1

Answer (score 4):

`ToolStripButton` derives from `ToolStripItem` which has a `ToolTipText` property.

As already explained, the `ToolStripItem` does not derive from the `Control` class so provides its own implementation to render tool tips. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4669343/577417) post may help you with customising the tooltip.

Comment: This helped but he didn't gave the code of the classes, like: TOOLTIP_XOFFSET, TOOLTIP_YOFFSET and toolTipText.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, [toolstripbutton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripbutton.aspx) class doesnt inherit from Control class unlike other System.Windows.Forms gui components. Perhaps in your code `e.AssociatedControl` is meant to be used with System.Windows.Forms controls. In short, I think MS hasnt decided to provide a tooltip for strip controls. I do not know your exact requirement, but for some alternative that might click, see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171703.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It`s old question, but answer is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-use-tooltips-in-toolstrip-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8):

1. Set the **ShowItemToolTips** property of the button to true.
2. Set the **ToolStripButton.AutoToolTip** property of the button to false.

*The AutoToolTip property is true by default for ToolStripButton. ToolStripDropDownButton, and ToolStripSplitButton.*

*A ToolStripButton uses its Text property for the ToolTip text by default. Use this procedure to display custom text in a ToolStripButtonToolTip.*